# Pass data to view controller before initializer when using segues. (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to swift and am trying to write an app with it.

I have a `UIViewController` that I am transitioning to.  I have designed the UI in interface builder and I intend to use segues to manage the transition.  However, the view controller relies on data that is passed into the view controller from the previous view controller.

If I have properties on my view controller then I will need to redefine my init method.  But I wouldn't normally call the `init` method; it would be called for me before `prepareForSegue`.  So I see a few possible solutions:

1. Make my variables optional (so I can pass them in `prepareForSegue`
   and update the view then).

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       let viewController: EventViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! EventViewController
       viewController.event = self.event
   }
   ```
2. Manually `init` my view controller and present it programmatically instead.
3. ???

Is there a third option?  If not, which of the previously mentioned 2 is better practice?

Comment: Please show your `prepareForSegue` code

Comment: Done but its pretty basic.  Its not that I can't do it that way; I'm asking if I should take that approach as opposed to some other approach

Comment: Option 1. You can even make them explicitly unwrapped optionals so that you don't need to keep unwrapping them and this will give you a runtime exception if you forget to set the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two possible options as you mentioned:

The first one is the easiest which is to pass the data in `prepareForSegue`. which you don't have to care about dismissing the controller or keeping a track of inner view controllers,because storyboard will take care of it.

The second way is to set a `Storyboard ID` in storyboard,for the controller you need to present programmatically, which need more things to handle, like to dismiss the controller or keep track of inner presented controllers.

```
let nextViewControllerName = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Storyboard ID") as! nextViewControllerName
nextViewControllerName.event = self.event
self.presentViewController(nextViewControllerName, animated: true, completion: nil).
```

At the end they does the same purpose.

***Note***: You should always pass the data before presenting the controller.

Comment: Chosen solution: pass data to implicitly unwrapped optional (thanks to @Paulw11) in `prepareForSegue`, then read the passed in data and update my view in `viewDidLoad` so it is ready before the view is presented.